# How to keep text sticky to image when using css3 transform

Tags: css

For showing transform i used jsfiddle, How to keep the sticky text to the image when transform, right now the text is constant,How to transform the text also along with the image

http://jsfiddle.net/U9g3c/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle, here I inserted the rotation and position change (the javascript-lines with `div.namehover`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5r6mx/

It would be more elegant if you would put the image and its title in a `<div>` and do all the rotation and reposition stuff on this `<div>`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5r6mx/5/ works good but the text on the image is so sharp and collapsing after hovering

Comment: What do you mean with "sharp"? "Collapsing"? Is it the quick movement of the text? Then you have to assign the same CSS3-attributes to it.

Comment: This one works on jsfiddle but when i use the same code in browser ,it is not working ..images also not transforming

Comment: Well, if you can take the idea from this answer and include it in your sites' code, it's alright. Sorry that I can't offer you the working solution for the browsers...

Answer (score 0):

You are only rotating the images. You have to set a `rotate`-class to the text wrapper as well.

Answer (score 0):

place your text and image in a shared div container and rotate that.